# Single-packet connect request at an extremely slow rate

Tags: nmap, network-scanners

I had been reading a blog post on trapx.com about how they go about threat analysis and following statement was made; "advanced attackers no longer perform noisy network scans. If they do network scans at all, they avoid detection by using single-packet connect requests on well-known ports, at an extremely slow rate".

How does one perform a single-packet connect request at an extremely slow rate? Is it possible to do this using nmap, if so how can it be done?

Comment: Have you read the nmap manual? They have a whole section on this.

Answer (score 5):

It simply means to do something like try a single connection attempt to a single port with a lot of time between.

But what "slow" means and how much time is not defined. 1/hr? 1/day? It depends on how stealthy the person wants to be and what their goals are.

nmap has many config options to do this (read the manual: https://nmap.org/book/man-performance.html)

For instance: `T0` sends a single connection attempt to one port at a time with 5 minutes in between. There are numerous finer config options where you can define exactly what you want to do.

I challenge the statement that noisy network scans are not performed by advanced hackers. It really depends on the situation. There is no reason to go slow on a public IP. Internal IPs, once you are inside and re-enumerating, would need this, but this is not something that only advanced attackers would do. It's just a response to the reality that noisy scans would be discovered and so would the attacker. Typically, the attacker would listen to traffic or do other enumerations to get a sense of what servers are available and what they serve.